# Replace multiple imgs with select using arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, select

-Hi everyone !-

After trying multiple things during months, I come to ask here if someone can solve my problem :
I want to have a page that shows multiple images successively and change all of these images when I change the selected index in my *select* bar, I don't want it to add the images but change the images by other images that I put in an array in javascript (I use links in arrays that will go in the *src* of the *img*), here is my code to understand more what I want and what I tried :

notes :

-I know it's not good to manipulate *img* with JavaScript but I don't want to use *iframe* in html because it will show up some empty pages whenever there is less images in the arrays than max possible *iframe* tags (300 here), and it's pretty buggy to load. (I also find *img* tag to fit well my requirements).

-Sorry if my code is messy or not good, and thank you for trying to help me !

**HTML**

```
    <div class="col-6">
        <select class="episodes listes form-select form-select mb-3" onchange="listeChap()">
            <option selected>Choose a Chapter</option>
            <option value="0">Chapter 1</option>   
            <option value="1">Chapter 2</option>
            <option value="2">Chapter 3</option>
            <option value="3">Chapter 4</option>
            <option value="4">Chapter 5</option>
            ...
        </select> 
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <img id="frame1" class="img-fluid"></img>
        <img id="frame2" class="img-fluid"></img>
        <img id="frame3" class="img-fluid"></img>
        <img id="frame4" class="img-fluid"></img>
        <img id="frame5" class="img-fluid"></img>
        ...
        <img id="frame300" class="img-fluid"></img>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
//here each "epsX" array is the X selected chapter, and in each chapter we have the img urls that I want to show

var eps1 = [
  'some_url_img.jpg',
  'some_url_img.jpg',
  'some_url_img.jpg',
];
var eps2 = [
  'some_url_img.jpg',
  'some_url_img.jpg',
  'some_url_img.jpg',
];
var eps3 = [
  'some_url_img.jpg',
  'some_url_img.jpg',
  'some_url_img.jpg',
];
.
.
.

function listeChap() {
  
    var elt = document.querySelector('select, .episodes');
    //the name of each arrays that we will add an X after to know which chapter it is
    var k = 'eps';
    var link, count, frameX;

    //300 is the total img tag number in HTML, didn't find how to put a var for it but it's ok like this I think
    for(count = 0; count < 300; count++){

        //having proper frame number for the getElementById
        frameX = 'frame' + count+1;

        //create a var that uses the array's name with a dyanmic number to have the links of the proper chapter => "epsX[]"
        link = eval(k + elt.selectedIndex + '[' + count + ']' + ';');

        //gives to the frameX id of img the proper link
        document.getElementById(frameX).src = link;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
frameX = 'frame' + count+1; // results frame01
```

which should be:

```
frameX = 'frame' + (+count + 1); // results frame1
// +count treats count as a number not a string
```

Simplified fiddle of yours: https://jsfiddle.net/2174q8nL/2/

Comment: Thank you very much !! It was all about this little thing,

Just to add something to finish the job, after doing it my page shows everything like it should but at the end of all the images, I find myself having little icons like these -> [https://prnt.sc/12t030b] . Is it coming from the method I used or from my own program unrelatedly ?

Comment: Im not sure but I think it comes because iteration (<300). I adjusted the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lu13gx9z/3/ Take a look at lines 20 to 29 and try it on your homepage too

Comment: Thank you for this tip, I didn't know how to have a var to count all children. I also found why it made this, it was because there was nothing in the selected array value, it results in : src="undefined", and not : src="". so I just have to put empty ' ', in the arrays. Anyways thank you very much for your help !